# How to handle dynamic number of input elements in React (Functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I am trying to place dynamic number of inputs using array.map like followings.
[Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/CxAIzrb2O_Vc)

The problem is that the length of array can exceed more than several Ks, so I think using state of string array is not the better choice then using Dom.
I tried to use unique ID to every input like `id={`withdraw_input_${index}`}` and it worked fine.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: I used same method to you, and it worked properly.

Comment: A few thousand strings is *nothing* to modern computers. If you're using React, better to work within the React ecosystem unless you've tested things and the alternative really does perform better by a nontrivial amount (which I'm skeptical of)

Comment: You're adding _thousands of inputs_ to a page? That doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: can you share your code logic?